# Bare metal STM32H755 (dual core) programming - Code won't start running

Tags: microcontroller, multicore, stm32h

I just bought a STM32H755ZI Nucleo board after having toyed with the Nucleo F411.

The problem I'm facing is:

When I flash the program into the micro-controller and debug, it seems as if I couldn't modify any register, and trying to do so, makes the debug get stucked there until I set a break point elsewhere.

This is the code that I'm flashing in the Cortex-M7:

```c
#define CORE_CM7
#include <stm32h755xx.h>

extern "C"{
    void SystemInit(void);
}

int f(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    int counter { 0 };
    while(1)
    {
        c = f(2,counter);
        counter++;
    }

    return 0;
}

void SystemInit(void)
{
    uint32_t timeout = 0x2000; //<<--Breakpoint set here. Gets stuck. Can only leave here by setting another breakpoint or hitting reset button
    while(!(PWR->CSR1 & 0x1 << 13) && timeout--)
    {
        __NOP();
    }
    PWR->CR3 &= ~ 0x1 << 4;
    PWR->CR3 &= ~ 0x1 << 3;
    PWR->CR3 &= ~ 0x1 << 2;
    PWR->CR3 |= 0x1 << 1;
    PWR->CR3 &= ~0x1 << 0;
}
```

Since its a bit confusing to explain, here's a video:
https://i.imgur.com/4bS7NkW.mp4

Basically, what the video shows is that the debugging stops on the line:

```c
while(!(PWR->CSR1 & 0x1 << 13) && timeout--)
```

And the only way to get to the main is by hitting the reset button on the device.
Also, When I clicked the Advance one step button in the debugger to go to the next line, that is, when I wanted to check that these register were being correctly set:

```c
PWR->CR3 &= ~ 0x1 << 4; // <<-- Debug stops here and doesn't advance 
PWR->CR3 &= ~ 0x1 << 3;
PWR->CR3 &= ~ 0x1 << 2;
PWR->CR3 |= 0x1 << 1;
PWR->CR3 &= ~0x1 << 0;
```

The debug won't just advance to the next lines and the register are not being set. And the code remains here until I hit the reset button.

I don't think that it is a thing about bad linking or building, because I think I'd get some errors.

Also, I've read the reference manual and its supposed that one of the first things to do when taking the microcontroller out of reset, is precisely what I'm trying to do in the `SystemInit` function, so, doesn't makes too much sense to me that I cant even perform the basic steps.

It's obvious but still mentioning it, I get no errors during compilation nor flashing:

Just for the record, these are the makefiles with which I build the sources for each core:

For the CM7:

```
CC := arm-none-eabi-gcc
CXX := arm-none-eabi-g++
TEST_CC := gcc
TEST_CXX := g++

INTERFACE := stlink-dap
BUILD_PATH := ../../Build
TARGET := ../../Build/dual_m7.elf
TEST_BUILD_PATH := ../../Build/Tests
TEST_TARGET := ../../Build/Tests/dual_test.elf
CORE_REL_PATH := ../../Core
STARTUP_REL_PATH := ../../Startup

# Define include directories
INC_DIRS := $(shell find ../../Core -type d -name .svn -prune -o -type d -print)
INC_FLAGS := $(addprefix -I, $(INC_DIRS))
C_FLAGS_DEF := $(addprefix -I, $(INC_DIRS)) -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m7   -g3 -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fexceptions -Wall -fstack-usage
CXX_FLAGS_DEF := $(addprefix -I, $(INC_DIRS)) -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m7   -g3 -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fexceptions -Wall -fstack-usage -fno-rtti -fno-use-cxa-atexit
TEST_C_FLAGS_DEF := -std=gnu11 -g3 -O0 -Wall $(addprefix -I, $(INC_DIRS))
TEST_CXX_FLAGS_DEF := -std=c++20 -g3 -O0 -Wall $(addprefix -I, $(INC_DIRS))
LINKER_FLAGS := -Wl,-Map=$(TARGET:.elf=.map),--cref -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m7   -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -lstdc++ -lsupc++ -Wl,--end-group -Wl,--print-memory-usage

CXX_SOURCES_CORE := $(shell find ../../Core -name '*.cpp'  -not -path "../../Core/m4/*")
C_SOURCES_CORE := $(shell find ../../Core -name '*.c'  -not -path "../../Core/m4/*")
TEST_CXX_SOURCES_CORE := $(shell find ../../Tests -name '*.cpp') $(shell find ../../Core -name '*.cpp'  -not -path "../../Core/m4/*" -not -path "../../Core/m7/*"  -not -name "sysmem.c" -not -name "syscalls.c")
TEST_C_SOURCES_CORE := $(shell find ../../Tests -name '*.c') $(shell find ../../Core -name '*.c'  -not -path "../../Core/m4/*" -not -path "../../Core/m7/*"  -not -name "sysmem.c" -not -name "syscalls.c")
STARTUP_SCRIPT_PATH := ../../Startup/startup_stm32h755xx.s
LINKER_SCRIPT_PATH := ../../Startup/stm32h755xx_flash_cm7.ld
OBJ_DIR := ../../Build/m7
TEST_OBJ_DIR := ../../Build/Tests/m7
CXX_OBJECTS := $(CXX_SOURCES_CORE:${CORE_REL_PATH}/%.cpp=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
C_OBJECTS := $(C_SOURCES_CORE:${CORE_REL_PATH}/%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
TEST_CXX_OBJECTS := $(TEST_CXX_SOURCES_CORE:../..//%.cpp=../../Build/Tests/m7/%.o)
TEST_C_OBJECTS := $(TEST_C_SOURCES_CORE:../..//%.c=../../Build/Tests/m7/%.o)
ASM_OBJECTS := $(STARTUP_SCRIPT_PATH:${STARTUP_REL_PATH}/%.s=$(OBJ_DIR)/Startup/%.o)
DEPS := $(CXX_OBJECTS:.o=.d) $(C_OBJECTS:.o=.d) $(ASM_OBJECTS:.o=.d)

-include $(DEPS)

all: clean build_project

build_project: $(TARGET)

flash: all
    openocd -f interface/stlink-dap.cfg -f board/st_nucleo_h745zi.cfg -c "program $(TARGET) verify reset exit"

build_test: clean_test $(TEST_TARGET)

run_test: build_test
    @./$(TEST_TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(CXX_OBJECTS) $(C_OBJECTS) $(ASM_OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -T $(LINKER_SCRIPT_PATH) $^ -o $@ $(LINKER_FLAGS)
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '

$(TEST_TARGET): $(TEST_CXX_OBJECTS) $(TEST_C_OBJECTS)
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)  
    $(TEST_CXX) $^ -o $@
    @echo 'Finished building test target: $@'
    @echo ' '

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: ../../Core/%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) -std=gnu++20 -c $< $(CXX_FLAGS_DEF) -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$@" -o "$@"

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: ../../Core/%.c
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) -c -std=gnu11 $< $(C_FLAGS_DEF) -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$@" -o "$@"

$(OBJ_DIR)/Startup/%.o: ../../Startup/%.s
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

$(TEST_OBJ_DIR)/%.o: ../../Tests/%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(TEST_CXX) -c $< $(TEST_CXX_FLAGS_DEF) -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$@" -o "$@"

$(TEST_OBJ_DIR)/%.o: ../../Tests/%.c
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(TEST_CC) -c $< $(TEST_C_FLAGS_DEF) -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$@" -o "$@"

$(TEST_OBJ_DIR)/%.o: ../../Core/%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(TEST_CXX) -c $< $(TEST_CXX_FLAGS_DEF) -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$@" -o "$@"

$(TEST_OBJ_DIR)/%.o: ../../Core/%.c
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(TEST_CC) -c $< $(TEST_C_FLAGS_DEF) -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$@" -o "$@"

.PHONY: clean clean_test

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)/* $(TARGET)

clean_test:
    rm -rf $(TEST_OBJ_DIR) $(TEST_TARGET)
```

Regarding the linker script and startup scripts, I'm using the officially hosted by STM32 on their GitHub.

Comment: I can't be sure if you are compiling the files correctly. Where do you tell the compiler about the target being a Cortex-M7 so it knows how to compile, and also, to the linker, to know with which libc to link it with? Also you seem to be using C++ which usually creates an extra layer of difficulty (might not be a huge one if you really want to write code with no drivers/HAL and spend countless hours deciphering the thousands of registers you need to get right to run the CPU core and peripherals the way you like). I suggest trying to make a blank CubeIDE project and see if it works better.

Comment: The makefile uses **board/st_nucleo_h745zi.cfg**, but in the question you've specified **STM32H755ZI**. Not sure if this is relevant though.

Comment: @Justme Thanks!. I didn't realized that I copied only part of the makefile